# Change buffer focus on enter?

Tags: buffers, plugin-nerdtree

I set up my `.vimrc` so that NERDTree automatically shows up on the left when opening vim for editing a file (`autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree`). This means, that NERDTree is the active buffer instead, and I have to press `<C-w>w` every time to focus on the file I want to edit.

How can I achieve this automatically?

Comment: How did you configure NERDTree to automatically show up? You probably want to change this customization so it would be useful to show it in the question. (Also, clearly not an answer but mandatory link on questions about Nerdtree and why not to use it: [oil and vinegar](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/))

Comment: `autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree` that's all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change your autocommand to execute `<c-w>w` after executing `NERDTree`. To do so you can use `wincmd` which is the equivalent of pressing `<C-w>` but with a command (see [`:h :wincmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3awincmd))

```
autocmd! VimEnter * NERDTree | wincmd w
```

Comment: Works for me without backslash as well: `au VimEnter *  NERDTree | wincmd w`